# Free up RAM for ERGM Model R

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph, sna, network-analysis

I'm attempting to run a large amount of data through the ergm function in R. By large, I mean my network graph object has 4,300 vertices and approximately 470,000 total edges. Covariates X,Y, and Z are all categorical data types. When I run this script, R studio will ultimately crash, as the model cannot handle that amount of gigs of information. I'm aware of the number of combinations that will be generated using the nodemix function; however, my analysis requires that I use this particular function given the nature of the study. I should also mention that I have reduced my data down as much as possible to account for its size.

I wanted to know if there was a way to drop any coefficients, by modifying the ergm function behind the scenes, with a -Inf. I could be wrong, but I feel like a majority of my nodemix combinations will have a -Inf coefficient; therefore, I can drop these unnecessary combinations and free up some RAM space for the function to completely run. I am not concerned with any combinations that have a -Inf. Hopefully this question makes sense. If you need any additional information please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    ergm_control <- control.ergm(drop= TRUE, MPLE.max.dyad.types=500000)
    ergm.factor.model <- ergm(sna.network ~ edges + 
                               nodemix('Covariate_X', base=1) +
                               nodemix('Covariate_Y', base=1) +
                               nodemix('Covariate_Z', base=1),
                               control=ergm_control)
```